# UIPageViewController setViewControllers not showing animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I have created UIPageViewController and loading pages. Everything works fine. I have Next button on each page. If user clicks on Next button on the page then I need to navigate to next page programatically.
My problem is, even though I am setting `animated:YES` for `setViewControllers` it dows not show animation while navigating to next page. App is displaying next page correctly but without animation.

I am using below code to navigate

```
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController]
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:YES
                                 completion:nil];
```

viewController will contain pages which I want to display.

Any help?